# Start iOS UI test session without Xcode or xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xctest, ui-testing, libimobiledevice

Test setup: a Windows PC and an iOS device connected by USB. Inside the device there is a MyAppUITests application that holds all XCTest-based UI tests required to test some UI-related things on this device. The question is: how to run this app so that it will actually perform tests and collect debug console output?

I am aware that there is a [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) lib that allows me to do this:

```
idevicedebug -u [udid] -e [some_env_variables] run [bundle_id]
```

But as far as I understand, this tool doesn't start a special UI test runner (as it described in [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/409/)) which in turn does all the automated UI testing and produces debug output.

I know that Xcode can do that via GUI or via `xcodebuild` utility like this:

```
xcodebuild -project myapp.xcodeproj -scheme "MyAppUITests" \
           -destination 'platform=iOS,name=MyTestDevice' test
```

And Xcode knows the magic trick on how to run test manager daemon that will run my UI tests correctly.

Is there a way to run my UI testing app through UI test using *libimobiledevice* or any other 3rd party tool available on Windows platform?

Answer (score 0):

libimobiledevice does not implement the APIs required to launch Xcode UI tests on non-Windows machines.

There are 3rd party tools on Windows which can run Xcode UI tests on Windows and Linux. Most (if not all) of them are designed to execute the Facebook WebDriverAgent and don't really support arbitrary Xcode UI tests, although it's probably not very difficult for them to support arbitrary Xcode UI tests.

The company I work for, Quamotion, provides such a tool. You can download our software and request a trial license at http://quamotion.mobi.

If you're still interested in this, feel free to reply and we'll try to make this work.